# asp.net error: This is an invalid webresource request

Tags: asp.net

I am getting a ton of error alerts from one of my asp servers in a web farm, and all the servers have the same machine key in their web.config files.
I've looked around here but didn't find this exact case answered.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

thanks for considering the question!

Here are some of the the error stacks (the query string is not from our app and could be part of something else):

> Error message: This is an invalid
>   webresource request. Stack trace:
>   at
>   System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   Source: System.Web Method: Void
>   System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)
>   Page:  QueryString: d=hAGTq1Iohid

These may have started when the Win 2003 server was patched.  Later dot.net frameworks were installed on three other servers but not on the one throwing the errors.

Most of the error seem related to decryption  but all servers in the same web farm now same machine key in their web config. But that has not stopped the errors.

Seeing as well :

```
"Length of the data to decrypt is invalid"
Error message: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid. Stack trace: at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount) at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock() at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo) at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s) at 
    System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessReques­t(HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.I­ExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

And Also

```
"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array"
Error message: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.
Stack trace:    at System.Convert.FromBase64CharArray(Char[] inArray, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(String input)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s)
   at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Source: mscorlib
Method: Byte[] FromBase64CharArray(Char[], Int32, Int32)
```

And

```
"Invalid view state"
Error message: Invalid viewstate.
Stack trace:    at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s)
   at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Source: System.Web
Method: System.String DecryptString(System.String)
```

Thanks again everyone.

Comment: Add this information to your question where it will be better formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure, but it looks like a hack attempt trying to exploit the very serious [.NET 'Padding Oracle' Crypto Attack,](http://threatpost.com/en_us/blogs/new-crypto-attack-affects-millions-aspnet-apps-091310) also [discussed by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/24/update-on-asp-net-vulnerability.aspx). There is [a patch available](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/30/asp-net-security-fix-now-on-windows-update.aspx), so if you find that your server is indeed vulnerable, make sure you patch it immediately, and take damage-control steps if it has in fact been compromised.

This could also be caused by a problem with your application. However, if you're suddenly seeing large amounts of these errors, especially without any recent changes to your app, my first thought would be an intrusion attempt. The method used to exploit this vulnerability would generate errors related to decryption and bad data length.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? This was a legit security issue and possible cause of OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

If this server is the only one that is both unpatched AND showing the errors then the very first thing I would do is run all the windows updates on it.

Actually, let me make that statement less complicated:  If this server is unpatched, start there and apply them.

**UPDATE**
You mentioned that the servers are throwing viewstate length errors.  One thing we found was that several components, notably data grids, shove a tremendous amount of data into viewstate.  Another thing was that several browsers would choke on this depending on length and not send all of it back.

After we made a particular web.config change this problem went completely away.  Even Safari 3 started working right.  Go to the `<system.web> <pages />` node and make the following change:

```
<pages maxPageStateFieldLength="500" />
```

This will cause viewstate to be broken up across multiple hidden fields at 500 bytes each.  It's an automatic split so none of your regular code has to change to support it.

You might play with the value, but essentialy some browsers can only send so much data back per input field.  Depending on the version I've seen safari choke when those values were much more than around 700 bytes or so.  Also firewalls and proxy servers might cause issues as well.  See the following for a bit more information: http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2007/04/17/viewstate-chunking-in-asp-net-2-0-maxpagestatefieldlength.aspx

Another option to pursue is to have viewstate cached locally and not send it across the wire at all.  Of course, that has implications in a web farm scenario so pick your poison.

Comment: Thank you everyone, appreciate it.  Well, they are all at the same windows patch level.  The app is asp.net 2.0, three of the servers in the farm have had .net 3.5 installed, one does not.  The one that does not have 3.5 throws the vast majority of the errors, but the others occasionally also throw the invalid viewstate and length errors.   This is an internal web site and security has not seen any hacking attempts against the web farm.  Again they all have the same machine key in the config.  Still looking...

Comment: @omaether: 3.5 was an extension to 2.0 so it's not really a new framework.  Also there were some bug fixes that went along with it that impacted the 2.0 framework

Comment: @omaether: See updates to my answer with regards to viewstate issues

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me just now on a web site, for no apparent reason: The request for a web resource generated "invalid request" error and all the scripts were broken.

Could be an update to the server, maybe..

My solution was to go to the IIS control panel and to generate a new machine key for the site.
This seems to solve the problem, whatever that was.